# Using Cordova FileTransfer in an ionic 2 app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic2

I want to do file uploads in my ionic 2 app.

In my code I have:

```js
var ft = new FileTransfer();
```

But `FileTransfer` is not recognised.

I have installed the Cordova file transfer plugin using:

```html
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
```

How do I import `FileTransfer` from the plugin so it is available.

I am using Angular 2 not Typescript.

Comment: Have you included cordova.js file included in your respective html? Have you registered deviceready event listener and invoking the plugin inside the listener?

Comment: Yes i have done all that but i think i am not invoking the plugin properly dont i have to import or use something like cordova.plugins....?

Comment: 'var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();' is suffice. Could you post your code to narrow down the problem?

Comment: I discovered the problem. I was not wrapping in "platform.ready().then" and not running on a physical device!

Comment: Thats what i meant bill. platorm,ready is the ionic equivalent for cordova's device ready event.                           ionic.Platform.ready(function(){
   do something that requires the deviceready event ...
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure to include cordova.js file in your respective html. Also register deviceready event listener and invoke plugin inside the listener.

In case of ionic platform, use platform.ready() which is an equivalent wrapper for deviceready event.

```
ionic.Platform.ready(function(){ //logic to invoke plugins });
```